# PHPUnit: How to Test a single Function in an Helper file

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, phpunit

I would like to test a new function in a helper file.

```
function isProductionSite() {
    return !(bool) preg_match('/admin|development/', request()->getHttpHost());
}
```

When I call this function in my test function I get my local address. Therefore I tried to mock the request()->getHttpHost.

```
public function testIsProductionSiteExpectFalse(): void
{
    $request = Mockery::mock(Request::class);
    $request->shouldReceive('getHttpHost')->once()->andReturn('admin.mydomain.de');
    $this->assertFalse(isProductionSite());
}
```

In the Tets Function $request->getHttpHost() would now output admin.mydomain.de. But getHttpHost() from the function to be tested (isProductionSite()) gives me the correct host.

**How can I set the HttpHost in the testcase so that the helper function outputs the manipulated host?**

Answer (score 1):

You're mocking an instance of `$request` but the instance being used by the function under test is not the mock, but presumably a global variable.

Dependencies should always be passed to the helper function. Just add `$request` as a parameter of `isProductionSite`.

Comment: thank you for your answer and the good advice!

Comment: glad the answer was useful. Remember to mark the answer as accepted if you think it resolved the question.